# java library to create a windows installer

Tags: java, windows-installer

I am looking for a java library that can be used to create a windows installer file for installing a java application. Can someone provide me with pointers to any such library that I could use.

Comment: Why don't you create a `jar` file instead? It works on all platforms.

Comment: I know how to create a jar file. I wanted to learn how to create a windows installer . There are other installers available that provide a GUI based environment for creating installers. I just was curious if the installer can be created and customized programatically. This is just for academic purposes.

Comment: jar + launch4j + inno setup could be an option

Comment: http://www.osalt.com/installshield OSS alternatives to installshield

Comment: We used [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Astrobleme, you can create a jar file instead of searching a java library that can be used to create a windows installer file for installing a java

However if you really want then check this:- [Open Source Installers Generators in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators). Also you can use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy the application.